# SSIS - Excel Pivoted file with 2 level of dynamic columns

Tags: ssis, unpivot

I have a file format from my customer to load. 
File is pivoted format and 2 level of column. (PointName & Size ). Also columns may vary time to time as more points may get added later. This should be handled dynamically.

[image: Source File]

I know the SSIS UnPivot transformations may not work due to dynamic column nature(File Meta-data may vary with new file) also 2 level of columns.

Request your help in case if anyone has come across this kind of file load requirements.

Adding the expected output file/table format below.

[image: Expected Output file/table format]